# In Javascript why is appending to TextArea field failing in one case but not the other

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I have a javascript function that takes a value from a select and append its to the end of a `textarea` field (mask) whenever a new selection is made from the `select`

```
function addToEditMask(select, mask)
{
    var selectedValue = document.getElementById(select).value;
    document.getElementById(mask).append(" + "+selectedValue);
}
```

This function is used by two different elements on the same page as follows:

```
     <div class="form-group">
        <label for="edit_filename_mask_mask" id="edit_filename_mask_masklabel">
            Mask
        </label>
        <textarea type="text" id="edit_filename_mask_mask" name="edit_filename_mask_mask" 
aria-describedby="edit_filename_mask_masklabel" class="form-control" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="editMaskVarList" id="editMaskVarListlabel">
            Mask Fields
        </label>
        <select class="mb-2 form-control custom-select" id="editMaskVarList" onchange="addToEditMask(&#x27;editMaskVarList&#x27;, &#x27;edit_filename_mask_mask&#x27;);">
            <option>
                acoustic (Acoustic)
            </option>
            .....
```

and

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="add_filename_mask_mask" id="add_filename_mask_masklabel">
            Mask
        </label>
        <textarea type="text" id="add_filename_mask_mask" name="add_filename_mask_mask" 
        aria-describedby="add_filename_mask_masklabel" class="form-control" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>
    </div>  

   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="addMaskVarList" id="addMaskVarListlabel">
        Mask Fields
    </label>
    <select class="mb-2 form-control custom-select" id="addMaskVarList" onchange="addToEditMask(&#x27;addMaskVarList&#x27;, &#x27;add_filename_mask_mask&#x27;);">
        <option>
            acoustic (Acoustic)
        </option>
        ......
```

In each case the select and the mask are both within a Bootstrap modal dialog.                But it only works for the second case (add_filename_mask_mask) not the first case (edit_filename_mask_mask)

I added some debugging to ensure

```
 function addToEditMask(select, mask)
    {
        var selectedValue = document.getElementById(select).value;
        document.getElementById(mask).append(" + "+selectedValue);
        alert('Adding to mask:'+mask+':'+scriptvar+':'+document.getElementById(mask).value);
    }
```

that the function was actually being called in both cases and all the variables a renamed correctly. Yet although there are no webconsole errors and the append() method doesnt report any error the value of mask doesnt change for edit_filename_mask_mask

I cannot create a SSCE since there seems to be no difference between the working and non working version. The **only** difference of note is that when modal dialog is first displayed `edit_filename_mask_mask` has a value but `add_filename_mask_mask` does not. However `edit_filename_mask_mask`  continues to fail if I blank out `edit_filename_mask_mask` , and `add_filename_mask_mask` when has value.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you try some safety checks ?

```
function addToEditMask(select, mask)
{
    var selectedValue = document.getElementById(select).value || "";
    var textarea = document.getElementById(mask);
    textarea.value = (textarea.value || "") + " + " + selectedValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable name is "select**ed**Value" and you call to "selectValue"

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo in creating question because in real code I have to simply select value slightly and I left detail out, now fixed.

Comment: yeah thats why im stumped